# XamPropertyGrid Custom Editor (Binding) not working

Tags: wpf, infragistics, propertygrid

I am using Infragistics' "XamPropertyGrid" in C# WPF,
I have created two classes as follow:

```
public class ClassA
{
    public ClassB B { get; set; }
}

public class ClassB
{
    public bool C { get; set; }
}
```

The Goal is to create a Custom Editor for PropertyGrid that contains a Checkbox Control and sets Property B.C of an instance of ClassA

Here is my xaml code:

```
<ig:XamPropertyGrid x:Name="pGrid">
        <ig:XamPropertyGrid.EditorDefinitions>
            <ig:PropertyGridEditorDefinition>
                <ig:PropertyGridEditorDefinition.TargetProperties>
                    <system:String>B</system:String>
                </ig:PropertyGridEditorDefinition.TargetProperties>
                <ig:PropertyGridEditorDefinition.EditTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox Content="XYC" IsChecked="{Binding Value.C}"></CheckBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ig:PropertyGridEditorDefinition.EditTemplate>
            </ig:PropertyGridEditorDefinition>
        </ig:XamPropertyGrid.EditorDefinitions>
    </ig:XamPropertyGrid>
```

At the start, I set the selected object for PropertyGrid like this:

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ClassA a = new ClassA();
        a.B = new ClassB();

        pGrid.SelectedObject = a;

    }
```

But when I check the Checkbox, Property C won't change. As far as I debugged the Value property inside Editor DataTemplate is null. (I put a converter inside Binding to check that.)

Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it was just a bug in XamPropertyGrid, all you need to do is to update to Version 2015.2